# My property conflict with transact sql property because of the name

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
Select * from InfinitusApp.CollaboratorUserLevels c
inner join InfinitusApp.ApplicationUsers a
on c.identity = a.Id
```

Where i rum this, return:

[image]

Because in my model CollaboratorUserLevels i have a property with Identity name,
return "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Identity'" even using alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have not turned off [quoted identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) you can use `"`

```
Select * from InfinitusApp.CollaboratorUserLevels c
inner join InfinitusApp.ApplicationUsers a
on c."identity" = a.Id
```